# javascript/jquery read directory listing w/o ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory, synchronous

I have a directory with webcam images on my server, but their names are not consecutive (some are missing). There is one image per minute, but the filename also includes the second the image was taken and this is changing from time to time.

So I would like to read in the complete directory listing and then further process it to make the images accessible to the visitor.

This is what I tried so far:

```
var Cache=function(st,mjd){
  this.update(st,mjd);
};
Cache.prototype.update = function(st,mjd) {
  d=mjd2date(mjd);
  if (this.st==st && this.year==d[0] && this.month==d[1]) {
    return;
  }
  this.st=st;
  this.year=d[0];
  this.month=d[1];
  this.days=new Array(31);
  for (i=0; i<31; i++) {
    this.days[i]=new Array(1440);
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: this.st+'/'+this.year+'_'+this.month,
    success: function(data){
      $(data).find('a:contains(jpg)').each(function(){
        console.log(this.href);
        this.days[14][123]=this.href;
      });
    }
  });
  console.log('days[14][123]='+this.days[14][123]);
}
```

My first problem is that I cannot access the object variables from inside the ajax call and also I can't pass something to it.

Second it would be easier for me, if there was a synchronous way. But I didn't find out how to implement this with javascript/jquery only.

I was searching for a solution now for some days, but couldn't find something straight forward ...

Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: Your first problem is because of the scoping of `this` - store it in a variable outside of the AJAX callback. The second point is not possible using JS alone.

Comment: What you are getting in `data`. Because you are using `$(data).find('a:contains(jpg)').each(function(){`. I think data is not the HTML. Its just an object.

Comment: So I should remove the 'this.' in front of days inside the ajax, right? But then it tells me 'Uncaught reference error'!?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Thank you for the hint. I think I can get it now to work.

Comment: @Samir: This part is working as expected (more or less ;-) ).